# Only display fields selected in TCheckListBox in a DBGrid via SQL

Tags: sql, database, delphi, ms-access, tadoquery

So I have a TDBGrid that displays the content of a Query via SQL.
I need to be able to only show the fields/columns that are selected in a TCheckListBox. How do I go about this problem?

[In this case the 'Lengte' field should not be included'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrpiF.png)

Answer (score 1):

The columns link back to the datasource so you can iterate over them until you find the one you want.

```
  for cnt := 0 to DBGrid1.Columns.Count -1 do
    if DBGrid1.Columns[cnt].FieldName = 'Lengte'
      then DBGrid1.Columns[cnt].Visible := false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!

```
var
  i, j: integer;
  arrColsToHide: array[0..11] of string;
begin
// resets all columns to VISIBLE and clears array
  for i := 0 to 11 do
    begin
      arrColsToHide[i]:= '';
      dbGridExport.Columns[i+1].Visible:= true;
    end;
// if item is not checked, add it to the array
  for i := 0 to 11 do
    if not(clbFieldsToExport.Checked[i])
      then arrColsToHide[i]:= clbFieldsToExport.Items.Strings[i];
// compares value of array to fieldname, and hide if same
  for j := 0 to 11 do
    begin
      for i := 1 to dbGridExport.Columns.Count-1 do
        if dbGridExport.Columns[i].FieldName = arrColsToHide[j]
          then dbGridExport.Columns[i].Visible := false;
    end;
end;
```